# SMO ScriptBatchTerminator Property doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm writing a powershell script to get the create script of a table and save it to a .sql file.

With the scripting options (part of SMO) I'm able to choose which parts of script should be included, like Foreign indexes, constraints, etc.

```
$opcionesscript = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions
$opcionesscript.DriAll = $true
```

However, the property 'ScriptBatchTerminator' which refers to 'GO' statements is not working when set true

```
$opcionesscript.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true
```

This the same result true or false:

```
$mydb.Tables["CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS"].Script($opcionesscript)


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS](
    [IDRELACION] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDLOCALIDAD] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COD_ART] [nvarchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [FECHA] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDRELACION] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS] TO [someuser] AS [dbo]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIO] FOREIGN KEY([IDLOCALIDAD])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIO] ([IDLOCALIDAD])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIO]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS_CATARTI] FOREIGN KEY([COD_ART])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CATARTI] ([COD_ART])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CAT_LOCALIDADES_INVENTARIOS_RELACION_ARTICULOS_CATARTI]
```

Why is not including 'GO' statements? Is there a bug or there is something that I'm missing? 
I'm creating a single batch .sql file to include those create table with its foreign keys, so those 'GO' are required.

Answer (score 2):

The frustrating thing is, if you script directly to a file, then the GO statements are added correctly.

But not if you script to a variable instead.

SMO is an amazing product that is poorly documented and poorly implemented.
It's really a shame.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to implement Big Data Clusters nobody uses and then spend additional work on deprecating it :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason SMO doesn't provide the GO statements in the script, I just found a way to workaround this issue by manually adding the GO statement after every script generated like this:

```
>$mydb.Tables["my_table"].Script($opcionesscript)| out-file c:\Tables.txt –append; “GO” | out-file c:\Tables.txt -append }
```